# How can I initialise an AnyVal value on scala?

Tags: scala

how can I initialise and AnyVal value?
If I initialise like this it shows 'Block cannot contain declarations'

`var value: AnyVal`

If I initialize like this it shows 'Required: Anyval, Found: Null'

`var value: AnyVal = null`

Can someone help me please?
Thank you.

EDIT

I tried using the Option[AnyVal] and it works perfectly. Thank you for the help.

Comment: You should not use `null` to define the absence of value/reference. You can use `Option` type like ```var value: Option[AnyVal]=None``` and then you can change it like ```value = Some(1)``` or any other AnyVal type.

Comment: Does 0 not working for you? You can also use java Number class `val value: Number = null`

Answer (score 1):

You can initialise it using `_`, like:

```
var value: AnyVal = _
```

BTW, it is better to use some Wrapper type, that expresses the absence of the value. In Scala it is possible using `Option` like:

```
var value: Option[AnyVal] = None
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I highly suggest using `val` over `var` and secondly why do you want to initialise to a default value and change it later? Almost many use cases can be achieved using immutability in Scala (which is good). If you could share your use case/example which is insisting you to use mutability, would be happy to take a look at it.

And it is always better to refrain from using `null` and use `Option` to represent absence, it avoids `NullPointerException`s